# Build docker image from github - submodules not cloning

Tags: git, docker, github

I have an application that consists of several services living in different Github repositories. To pinpoint a global version, there is an additional repository that includes the former as Git submodules.

It would be nice if I can build Docker containers using this repo, eg. `docker build github.com/org/repo#1.0:admin` (to build the `admin` container). Without submodules this works, however if `admin` is a submodule, it is not fetched (I think `docker build` is not using `git clone --recursive`), and thus `docker build` will give this error:

> `unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /tmp/docker-build-git205355788/admin/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

Indeed the directory `admin` is empty. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories says it should copy recursively but it seems it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

> `> docker --version`
>
> `Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do in your Dockerfile

install git

git clone

then build

See for example

https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/nethogs_git/

Comment: Well I guess I could go that way, so far I've kept a Dockerfile in the Github repos themselves. But I can just extract the whole Docker infrastructure and keep it seperate. It is a workaround though, from the Docker documentation the setup I described above should work too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
RUN git submodule init && git submodule update
```

In your Dockerfile